# [cold-weather], [hot-weather], and [temperature]

Tags: discussion, tagging

[hot-weather](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hot-weather) actually hasn't been created yet, but assume for the purposes of this discussion that it is / will be.

I've noticed that posts have been using either or both [temperature](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperature) and [cold-weather](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-weather) to cover essentially the same topics. I think we should use only [hot-weather](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hot-weather) and [cold-weather](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-weather) for hot and cold weather respectively, and reserve temperature for talking about the temperature of physical items that one has to get or keep warmer or cooler than the surrounding environment.  Something about, perhaps, how hot do I have to get X food, or possibly the [cooler question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/492/18).

Anyone have an opinion one way or another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see some usefulness to the [cold-weather](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-weather) and [hot-weather](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hot-weather) (and perhaps their partner in crime, [all-weather](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/all-weather)?), but I don't think [temperature](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperature) would be very useful. It's difficult to tell what it's about just by looking at it, which will only lead to confusion and misuse. It sounds like a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that should be avoided.

Comment: +1, temperature doesn't seem like a useful tag to me - too vague.

Comment: Tags like "all-weather" end up not being used as people are likely to see tags as distinguishing. Would my post on uses of belly button fluff for fire lighting really be tagged "all-weather", "all-climates", "all-seasons", "worldwide", "language-independent", "fire-lighting", "survival", I think not :)